# Using RestSharp in ASP.Net page vs WinForms App

Tags: asp.net, .net, winforms, restsharp

Hope someone can help...

I'm using RestSharp (105.2.3) to call another company's Web API.  While I was discovering/figuring out the other company's API, I created a wrapper class that uses the RestSharp library to make the API calls and I tested it with a WinForm app as I went along.

A few days later, I had everything working perfectly and could access every method/function on their API via my wrapper class.

When I use my wrapper class in an ASP.Net app running on my PC, the IRestResponse content is always blank and the StatusCode is always 0.  Is there something obvious that I'm missing?  My class works flawlessly when used in a WinForm app but not at all when used in an ASP.Net app.

I'm using IIS 7.5.7600 on Windows 7 - 64Bit

RestSharp 105.2.3

.Net 3.5 (on both the WinForm & WebApp)

My code is:

```
Dim client = New RestClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("apiURL").ToString)
client.Authenticator = New HttpBasicAuthenticator(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("apiUser").ToString, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("apiToken").ToString)
Dim request = New RestRequest("courses?limit={limit}&offset={offset}", Method.[GET])
request.AddParameter("limit", 200, ParameterType.UrlSegment)
request.AddParameter("offset", 0, ParameterType.UrlSegment)
Dim response = client.Execute(request)
Dim Courses As List(Of Course) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Course))(response.Content.ToString())
```

Comment: Use a tool such as Fiddler to compare to the requests and verify that they're the same.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Mason.  It appears that when client.Execute(request) is called, Fiddler sees nothing, as if it never was called.  The same line of code is recorded by Fiddler when it is called from within the WinForm app.  Any thoughts as to why it's being blocked from inside the WebApp??